# mobile phone application with OCR

Tags: ocr

I am going to develop my mobile application and i am new in it and i want 
To know which programming language is good is it Symbian C++ or QT? You should know that i use Nokia N95 or in general mobiles with Symbian OS. 
and my app.contains OCR (object character recognition) and TTS (Text To Speech).

Answer (score 0):

C++ is better, I think.

I am also trying different OCR SDKs in symbian platform. I found C++ and C are best choices for OCR application in mobile. You know most OCR engines are computing-intensive, so for ExperVision OCR, they use C/C++, for Abyy, they use C++, for Tesseract free OCR, they use C++ too.

C++ also give you highest efficiency and convenient when calling OCR SDK or other necessary image processing libraries. C++ also have good resources in other GUI and communication development library.

Anyway, I prefer C++.